# How to do fraud detection by kafka stream with dynamic changed rules?

Tags: drools, apache-kafka-streams

I want to use kafka stream in fraud detection scenario. But how to use it with dynamic changed rules engine (eg. Drools rules)? My thought is populate drools rules in a kafka topic which treat as KTable, while store coming customer data in another kafka topic treat as KStream, then join KStream with KTable, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could check https://github.com/TouK/nussknacker? You will get dynamic rules engine, it has several execution engines (flink, embedded, kubernetes based), you can also write your own.